# iOS twitterkit 3.1.3(3.1.1) install manually. "This app was unable to be installed."

Tags: ios, twitterkit

https://ton.twimg.com/syndication/twitterkit/ios/3.1.1/Twitter-Kit-iOS.zip

I install TwitterKit 3.1.1 manually by this link.

But can't load to simulator, "**This app was unable to be installed**."

Also can't load to device(iPhone), "**App installation failed.** Could not write to the device."

How to fix it ?

Please advice...

Comment: My guess is that they don't include a simulator build of the framework; you will need to run on a real device

Answer (score 1):

This problem stems from an improper setup as mentioned by [ishkawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677105/ishkawa).  I'd like to post the entire error in its entirety in case anyone else runs into the issue:

From:
~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/coresimulator.log:

: installApplication:withOptions:error:: Error Domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain Code=1 "This app could not be installed at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This app could not be installed at this time., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f83c58969c0 {Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=11 "Bundle at path /Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08FE45B1-C973-45B4-816F-443BD6060102/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9KckPp/extracted/Payload/TwitterPart2.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist" UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=MissingBundleExecutable, FunctionName=-[MIExecutableBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=78, NSLocalizedDescription=Bundle at path /Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08FE45B1-C973-45B4-816F-443BD6060102/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.9KckPp/extracted/Payload/TwitterPart2.app/Frameworks/TwitterCore.framework has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist}}}

The problem is that TwitterCore was embedded.

1. Open the app's Xcode project or workspace.
2. Go to the app target's General configuration page.
3. Remove TwitterCore.framework from the Embedded Binaries section.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you accidentally embedded TwitterCore.
Removing TwitterCore from embedded binaries fixed this issue in my case.

Actually, [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/installation) says:

- Embed TwitterKit only.
- Link both of TwitterKit and TwitterCore.

Confirm you set up your project correctly.